# Namespace 'app' not bound, in Android Studio with external lib from Maven

Tags: android-studio

I get Namespace 'app' not bound whenever I try to specify the properties for the external libs UI elements.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_database"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="dbclicked"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#ffff7f31"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_database"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/db"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_database"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:text="@string/db"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:autoText="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.0' is used in build.gradle and I am running the latest version of the Android Studio with updates.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Add

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your root element

Comment: Thanks, it was such a noob error. Overlooked it by mistake

Comment: What is this link?

Comment: Any reference or document? 
Could you please also make some descriptions? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Simply select the error (touch the error by mouse) and press.   "ALT+ENTER"    it will automatically solve the error.

Comment: This doesn't make sense all the time, need to be more precise when answer the question.

Answer (score 11):

Add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to root like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction = "ifRoom"
        />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have opened like 10 questions just like yours trying to solve this issue, but all the solutions never worked for me. Am going to post this to every other question similar to this one, just in case someone else get stuck in my position.

What worked for me:
Open Tools> SDK manager then press edit SDK location. Now note the location, open it using windows explorer, copy the SDK folder to another location eg Desktop, Documents. Once done go back to edit SDK location then choose a new location where you pasted the SDK folder, press next then wait. It should be fixed.