# What is "app" in android xml?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use this [library](https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry)

What should I replace app with?

```
   <com.devmarvel.creditcardentry.library.CreditCardForm
        android:id="@+id/credit_card_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:helper_text_color="@color/yellow_500"
        app:include_helper="false"
        app:include_zip="false"/>
```

I'm having this error when adding the xml:

[image]

Comment: Nothing. Why do you think you have to replace it?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I've already read that link, but it didn't help me. That leads me to ask this question.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question. Go into more detail about what you really need

Comment: I've just added the error message above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353835/namespace-app-not-bound-in-android-studio-with-external-lib-from-maven

Comment: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` put this in the parent layout, and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks. I've added that and the error is gone. But I'm still having issues when customising it "app:include_exp="false". Guess it's something else that causes the customisation failure.

Answer (score 3):

That is a **namespace**, usually used for applying custom attributes to custom views. As in your case, you have a custom view **CreditCardForm** which has it's own attributes.

Attributes are defined in the library inside **res/attrs.xml**

To resolve your error, add the line

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```